# Why is my (chez) scheme symbol not visible when running with --program, but is with --script?

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

I'm trying to get my head around using Chez Scheme and running programs with it, and I encountered a thing I can't quite make sense of. Lets say I wanted to have a scheme program that did some stuff, defined some functions, and then ran the REPL. This is what I got just playing around with it:

```
(import (chezscheme))

(define test-function
  (lambda (x y)
    (+ (* 2 x) y)))

(display (test-function 3 4))
(new-cafe)
```

Doesn't do anything fancy, just defines a function, displays a test output, then starts the REPL using new-cafe (which I found in the Chez Scheme docs). Here's my question, this works fine if I run it using `--script`:

```
$ scheme --script test.ss
10
> (test-function 5 6)
16
```

But `test-function` is not defined inside the REPL when I run it as `--program`:

```
$ scheme --program test.ss
10
> (test-function 5 6)
Exception: variable test-function is not bound
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

Notice, however, that it did print the 10, so `(test-function 3 4)` does work inside `test.ss`, it just doesn't work inside of `(new-cafe)`.

There's something fundamental I don't understand here. What, exactly, is the difference between `--script` and `--program`, and why doesn't REPL recognize `(test-function)` when running as `--program` (even though it IS recognized outside of `(new-cafe)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--script` evaluates expressions one at a time in the mutable [interaction environment](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/use.html#./use:s11).

`--program` evaluates the expressions as if they were wrapped in a [`top-level-program`](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/libraries.html#./libraries:s14) form.

`new-cafe` evaluates its expressions within the interaction environment. Definitions within a `top-level-program` form do not affect the interaction environment, so `new-cafe` doesn't see them.

What you need to do is

- make an environment containing `test-function`,
- parameterize `interaction-environment` to that environment, then
- evaluate `new-cafe`.

In order to make an environment containing `test-function`, `test-function` must be exported from a library. The easiest way to do that is to create a separate file.

**mylib.ss**

```
(library (mylib)
  (export test-function)
  (import (chezscheme))

  (define test-function
    (lambda (x y)
      (+ (* 2 x) y))))
```

**test.ss**

```
(import (chezscheme))
(parameterize ([interaction-environment
                (copy-environment (environment '(chezscheme) '(mylib)) #t)])
  (new-cafe))
```

```
$ scheme --program test.ss
> (test-function 5 6)
16
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Is the reason for having the immutable/mutable environment distinction because of performance? Allows you to inline calls and things because the environment isn't mutable?

Comment: Yes. Chez Scheme optimizations take advantage of environment immutability. Immutable environments are also useful in a plug-in scenario where you want plug-in code to execute in a precise environment yet not be able to break things for other plugins. I'm sure there are other reasons immutable environments are valuable, too.